# Produce a facet with an overall group in ggsurvplot in R

Tags: r, survminer

In R, I am using `ggsurvplot_facet` to produce survival curves plotted for groups `sex` as a facet stratified by a variable `ecog`. However, I would like to have an overall group as well in the same facet as well. Is this possible?

`ggsurvplot_add_all` did not help.

Here is some example data:

```
library(survminer)
lung$ecog <- ifelse(lung$ph.ecog == 0, 0, 1)
fit <- surv_fit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

fig_os <- ggsurvplot_facet(fit, data = lung, facet.by = 'ecog')
```

[image]

I need a survival curve for the whole population, independent of `ecog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheat a little bit, by row-binding `lung` to a copy of `lung` where in the latter `ecog` has been replaced with a constant.

1. Cheat, making a copy, setting ecog to 2, row-binding, and changing ecog in the row-bound dataset to a factor.

   ```
   lung2 <- copy(lung)
   lung2$ecog <- 2
   lung2 <- rbind(lung,lung2)
   lung2$ecog <- factor(lung2$ecog,labels = c("0", "1", "Overall"))
   ```
2. Then use your code above, but using `lung2` as the dataset.

   ```
   fit <- surv_fit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung2)
   fig_os <- ggsurvplot_facet(fit, data = lung2, facet.by = 'ecog')
   ```

Output:

[image: ecog]

Comment: This is a nice method. I thought and hoped for something integrated in `survminer` that I was not aware of.